# Sharing a value using decorators

Tags: python, decorator

I'm trying get to know decorators, and I have a problem with sharing value, because I can't change it:

```
def my_decorator(func1,func2) :

    def wrapper() :
        a=0
        func1()
        func2()
        print(a)

    return wrapper


def first_lazy_function() :
    a=1
    print(a)

def second_lazy_function() :
    a=2
    print(a)




functionDecorator=my_decorator(first_lazy_function,second_lazy_function)

functionDecorator()
```

My output is :

```
1
2
0
```

Instead:

```
1
2
2
```

What I must to do to get an expected value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using three local variables called `a`, not a global variable called `a`
Try first line in the script `a=0` and then in every function do `global a` and then `a=1` or `a=2`